# Detect MySQL InnoDB via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

How can I detect if a MySQL database table is using the InnoDB storage engine from within a PHP program?

The reason - the PHP program needs to utilize database transactions. InnoDB supports transactions. MyISAM (the MySQL default storage engine) does not. The program needs to fail if transactions are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'xxx'
```

This will give you (among other things) an Engine column, which is what you want.

or if u want it at database level

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename\G`

Over:

`SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'xxx'`

Because you can easily specify tables outside of the current database, i.e.:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE database.table\G`

The `\G` formats the output nicely, but it is optional.